# vba to find word or phrase then highlight the entire paragraph that follows it

Tags: highlight, paragraph

I've used the following code to find a key word or phrase then highlight the line -- but can't figure out how to make it highlight the entire paragraph and/ or list that follows it...

For example:
(ideally, highlighting this paragraph AND the list that provides further details would be best -but if only the paragraph is achievable, that's better than nothing):

"The Contractor shall turn in monthly status reports within ten business days after the end of each month. The report should include:
(a) Accomplishments
(b) Meetings and Outcomes
(c) Completed Travel and Purpose of Travel"

I've researched several commands and looked for examples but still at a loss as a novice. I tried "wdParagraph" but couldn't get that to work. Located refs of maybe using a "paragraph.range.select" and also found a note that advised these "start" and "end" terms (below) to select a paragraph.. but not sure how to achieve this? Hoping someone has an example of how to accomplish this as it will help greatly with quickly identifying hundreds of software reqs out of a 100 page word doc.. so frustrated!
 * Selection.StartOf Unit:=wdParagraphm
 * Selection.MoveEnd Unit:=wdParagraph

```
Sub Find_Highlight_Word_to_End_of_Line()

'BUT NEED IT TO HIGHLIGHT THROUGH END OF PARAGRAPH
'AND HIGHLIGHT LISTED ITEMS IF APPLICABLE
'LIKE THE LISTS IN THE EXAMPLE DOCUMENT

Dim sFindText As String
'Start from the top of the document
 Selection.HomeKey wdStory

sFindText = "Contractor Shall"
Selection.Find.Execute sFindText

Do Until Selection.Find.Found = False
Selection.EndKey Unit:=wdLine, Extend:=wdExtend

        Selection.Range.HighlightColorIndex = wdYellow
        Selection.MoveRight
        Selection.Find.Execute

Loop
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

A couple of awesome experts shared 2 methods with me to achieve the full paragraph highlighting I needed.. Hope these help others! Fascinating to see different ways to achieve the same result!

Method 2 Code (Alternative) is shorter:

```
Sub Highlight_Paragraph() 
    Dim oRng As Range 
    Set oRng = ActiveDocument.Range 
    With oRng.Find 
        Do While .Execute(FindText:="Contractor Shall") 
            oRng.Paragraphs(1).Range.HighlightColorIndex = wdYellow 
            oRng.Collapse 0 
        Loop 
    End With 
lbl_Exit: 
    Set oRng = Nothing 
    Exit Sub 
End Sub
```

Method 1 Code (MatchWildcards=False):

```
Sub Demo()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
With ActiveDocument.Range
  With .Find
  .ClearFormatting
  .Replacement.ClearFormatting
  .Text = "Contractor Shall"
  .Replacement.Text = ""
  .Forward = True
  .Wrap = wdFindStop
  .Format = True
  .MatchWildcards = False
  .Execute
  End With
  Do While .Find.Found
  .Duplicate.Paragraphs.First.Range.HighlightColorIndex = wdYellow
  .Start = .Duplicate.Paragraphs.First.Range.End
  .Find.Execute
  Loop
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```